# Google Cloud Platform: How do I rename a Google Cloud Platform project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to rename a Google Cloud Platform project? If so, how?

I don't need to change the project ID or number. But I do want to change the project *name* (the name used by/for humans to identify a cloud platform project).

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

1. Use the hamburger menu in the top left to switch to the "IAM & Admin" section
2. Click Settings
3. Type the new name
4. Press Save
5. Reload the page

For those wondering how to change the project ID, [the official documentation says](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7014113?hl=en):

> A project ID cannot be changed after the project is created, so if you are creating a new project, be sure to choose an ID that you'll be comfortable using for the lifetime of the project.

Comment: This method will rename the public name of your project, to rename also the private name go to "PERMISSIONS -> SETTINGS"

Comment: @Adam I tried finding the rename/pencil for the `My First Project` example project created for you after signing up. To no avail :(.

Comment: Hey @Zero3, better update the answer (I did it for you this time)

Comment: "_Click your project in the top right_" Top right of what screen?

Comment: @AlessandroMuzzi Where is `PERMISSIONS -> SETTINGS`? I can't find it.

Answer (score 61):

The easiest way it to go via the hamburger menu in the top left >  "IAM & Admin" > Settings.
These are the [screenshots to the Google Cloud Product Settings](http://blog.optimal.io/How-to-change-name-of-project-Google-Cloud/)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can change the project name using **gcloud projects update** command.

First of all, you need to get the associated project ID.

```
gcloud projects list
```

Here is the example command.

```
gcloud projects update your-old-project-id --name="New project name"
```

For more information please refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/update) official documentation.

**Note**: You cannot change the ID of a project's **ID** or **Number**,you can only change the **Name**.

Comment: This is the best answer, IMO. Took me two minutes using [the online Google Cloud Shell](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to change your project in a few seconds is to:

1. Click on the three dots on the left of your profile and then on the `Project settings`. No matter where you are now in the console, this option will be available.

[image]

2. Change your project name and Click `SAVE`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Google console menus have changed since @Sphinxxx posted an answer to this question in 2017. (Unless for some reason my Google account is different than others.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

It is still possible to rename the project, but in order to get to the Settings page, you must first go through the "IAM & admin" menu.  Here are the steps I did:

- Choose the **project name** from the menu just to the right of "Google APIs"
- Open the **navigation menu** by clicking on the three bars ("hamburger") just to the left of "Google APIs"
- Hover over **IAM & admin** in order to see that menu
- Click on **Settings** to open the settings page where you can modify the project name

[Screen shot of IAM & admin menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4UpJ.png)

**NOTE**: it is also possible to directly go to the settings page via the URL using the project id:
 - https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?project=your-project-id

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the hamburger menu in the top left to switch to the "IAM & Admin" section.
2. Click Settings.
3. Type the new name.
4. Press Save.
5. Reload the page

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to IAM
2. Settings
3. Rename your project

[image: GCP]